# Cambiar valores de una función a partir de un color heredado en Sass

Tags: html, css, sass

Estoy aprendiendo un poco de Sass y estoy intentando hacer unas formas de bloques sólo con divs de colores, cambiando y rotando sus posiciones. El `div` inicial a partir del cual creo los bloques más grandes es este:

```
<div class="brick">
  <div class="brick__face brick__face--top"></div>
  <div class="brick__face brick__face--front"></div>
  <div class="brick__face brick__face--side"></div>
</div>
```

Ese sería un bloque de 1x1, si quisiera hacer un bloque de 2x2 sería algo así:

```
<div class="block--width-2">
  <div class="brick">
    <div class="brick__face brick__face--top"></div>
    <div class="brick__face brick__face--front"></div>
    <div class="brick__face brick__face--side"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="brick">
    <div class="brick__face brick__face--top"></div>
    <div class="brick__face brick__face--front"></div>
    <div class="brick__face brick__face--side"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="brick">
    <div class="brick__face brick__face--top"></div>
    <div class="brick__face brick__face--front"></div>
    <div class="brick__face brick__face--side"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="brick">
    <div class="brick__face brick__face--top"></div>
    <div class="brick__face brick__face--front"></div>
    <div class="brick__face brick__face--side"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Los bloques de 1x1 por defecto son rojos, heredan el color de la clase `block`

```
.block {
  background: $color-red;
}

.brick__face--top {
  background: inherit;
}
```

La cara frontal es más clara

```
.brick__face--front {
    background: lighten($color-red, 10%);
}
```

y la cara izquierda es más oscura

```
.brick__face--side {
    background: darken($color-red, 10%);
}
```

Lo que quiero lograr es que añadiéndole un modificador a la clase `block`, las 3 caras de `brick` hereden el color de alguna forma. Había pensado en una `function` que me permitiese hacerlo, pero no me permite trabajar con `inherit` como valor

```
.block--color-white {
  background: $color-white;
}

@function lighten-or-darken($color, $lighten: true) {
  @if $lighten {
    @return lighten($color, 10%);
  } @else {
    @return darken($color, 10%);
  }
}
```

De modo que lo único que tendría que hacer sería:

```
.brick__face--front {
    background: lighten-or-darken(inherit)
}

.brick__face--side {
    background: lighten-or-darken(inherit, false)
}
```

Aquí el enlace a Codepen:
https://codepen.io/gabriel-ortiz/pen/PoNGvMj?editors=0100

Comment: Sé que una posible solución sería añadir un modificador para cada elemento, pero estaba intentando conseguir una solución algo más automatizada

Answer (score 0):

al final la solución que conseguí fue añadiendo modificadores a todos los sub-elementos según el color que quería.

```
$colors: (
  "white": #ffffff,
  "black": #0f0f10,
  "red": #c20f00,
  "blue": #2374c6,
  "yellow": #ffdd22
);

@each $name, $color in $colors {
  .block--color-#{$name} {
    background: $color;
  }
  .brick__face--front-#{$name} {
    background: lighten-or-darken($color);
  }
  .brick__face--side-#{$name} {
    background: lighten-or-darken($color, false);
  }
}
```

Y ya que para el Html estaba usando Pug, añadí una variable en los mixin para poder colocar el modificador de color en todos los elementos.

```
mixin brick-1x1(color)
  .brick
    .brick__face.brick__face--top
    .brick__face.brick__face--front(class='brick__face--front-' + color)
    .brick__face.brick__face--side(class='brick__face--side-' + color)

mixin replicate-brick(color, n)
  - var i = 0;
  while i < n
    +brick-1x1(color)
    - i++;

mixin brick-size(color="red", n=4, isLonger3=false)
  if isLonger3
    .block--width-5(class='block--color-' + color)
      +replicate-brick(color, n)
  else if n > 4
    .block--width-3(class='block--color-' + color)
      +replicate-brick(color, n)
  else if n <= 4 && n > 1
    .block--width-2(class='block--color-' + color)
      +replicate-brick(color, n)
  else
    .block(class='block--color-' + color)
      +replicate-brick(color, n)
```